# Multi-level List in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am struggling with a pretty noob thing which is pretty trivial in PHP but I am fairly new to Python. I have a method that queries the database for user test data then builds a string with a few key:values that will get passed to the template.

```
def getTests(self, id):
    results = []
    count = 0
    tests = TestAttempts.objects.all().filter(user_id=id)

    for test in tests:
        title = self.getCourseName(test.test_id)
        results[count].append([{'title': title, 'finished': test.grade_date_time, 'grade': test.test_grade}])
        count += 1
    return results
```

I am looking to make a multi-level list that I can loop through in the template to display the test title, finished date, and grade.

I am getting the following error:

```
list index out of range
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dash/history/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
```

Any help on the best approach would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need count variable.

```
results.append([{'title': title, 'finished': test.grade_date_time, 'grade': test.test_grade}])
```

[list.append(x)](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) operation will add an item to the end of the list anyway.

Comment: Also, you probably want to append just the dictionary rather than a list containing the dictionary. This code will result in a list like `[[{'title': 'foo', ...}], [{'title': 'lol', ...}]]`, where if you just do `results.append({...})` it'll be the easier-to-work-with `[{'title': 'foo', ...}, {'title': 'lol', ...}]`.

Comment: Thanks for this as well, not sure why had the dict in the list but completely unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Instead of indexing with `count`

```
results[count].append([{'title': title, 'finished': test.grade_date_time, 'grade': test.test_grade}])
```

You should directly call the `append` method:

```
results[count].append([{'title': title, 'finished': test.grade_date_time, 'grade': test.test_grade}])
```

Also, you're appending a list containing a single dictionary. Unless what you wanted to do is `extend` the results by adding each dictionary to the list (which isn't happening in the example), it's probably unnecessary:

```
results[count].append({'title': title, 'finished': test.grade_date_time, 'grade': test.test_grade})
```